# Python skips while-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to make tick-tack-toe. I implemented a while loop to intercept invalid input. But the program just goes on with programs no matter the input.

```
def coordinates(A,B,C):
    
    while True:                                      #while-Schleife to intercept false input
        Reihe = input("Welche Reihe(Buchstabe)")
        Spalte = int(input("Welche Spalte(Zahl)"))
        
        if isinstance(Reihe,str):
            if isinstance(Spalte,int): 
                if Spalte>0 and Spalte<4:
                    break                             #input ok = breakout of loop
                else:
                    print("Zahl zu groß")
                    continue
            else:
                print("Eine Zahl eingeben")
                continue
        else:
            print("Einen Buschstaben eigeben")    
            continue


    if Reihe.upper()== "A":              #Check Place in table and if not occupied by other player
        if A[Spalte -1] != "O":
                A[Spalte-1] = 'X'
        
    elif Reihe.upper()== "B":
        if B[Spalte -1] != "O":
                B[Spalte-1] = "X"
        
    elif Reihe.upper()== "C":
        if C[Spalte -1] != "O":
                C[Spalte-1] = "X"
        
    else:
        print("Nur A,B oder C")

    print(A)
    print(B)
    print(C)


A = ["","",""]
B = ["","",""]
C = ["","",""]

coordinates(A,B,C)
```

My output:

```
Welche Reihe(Buchstabe)1
Welche Spalte(Zahl)1
Nur A,B oder C
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
['', '', '']
```

"Reihe" is obviously not a string but the program just escapes the loop.

Comment: It is a string. What makes you think it isn't? BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: See [the docs for `input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input): "reads a line from input, converts it to a string, and returns that"

Comment: So since `Reihe` is in fact a string, what do you want to happen? Do you want your program to make sure that it's not numeric, or to make sure that it's one of `"A", "B", "C"`?

Answer (score 0):

Given your example input "1" for the Reihe, the value ("1") is a string and so the test succeeds.

If you're able to use a tool such as Visual Studio Code, you can step through your code in the debugger and prove this to yourself.

You could consider:

```py
Reihen = ["A","B","C"]
if Reihe in Reihen:
  ...
```